# GAN is stuck during training right form the beggining

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to build a GAN using MNIST data-set, and when I start training it, I can see that both the generator and discriminator are stuck (.i.e. the loss values won't change and the generator outputs the same white noise meaningless images). I tried changing the loss functions for both the discriminator and generator, the learning rate, adding and removing layers but none of the attempts worked. Attached is my code:

```
def tensor_to_plt_im(im: torch.Tensor):
    return im.permute(1, 2, 0)


def d_loss(discriminator_generated_x, discriminator_true_x):
    return -0.5 * torch.mean(torch.log(discriminator_true_x + 1e-8)) \
           - 0.5 * torch.mean(torch.log(1 - discriminator_generated_x + 1e-8))


def gen_loss(discriminator_generated_x, discriminator_true_x):
    return -1 * d_loss(discriminator_generated_x, discriminator_true_x)


def gen_loss_non_saturating(discriminator_generated_x):
    return -0.5 * torch.mean(torch.log(discriminator_generated_x + 1e-8))


def d_loss_least_squares(discriminator_generated_x, discriminator_true_x):
    return 0.5 * torch.mean(torch.square(discriminator_true_x + 1e-8 - 1)) \
           + 0.5 * torch.mean(torch.square(discriminator_generated_x + 1e-8))


def gen_loss_least_squares(discriminator_generated_x):
    return 0.5 * torch.mean(torch.square(discriminator_generated_x + 1e-8 - 1))


class MNISTGen(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_input_channels):
        super(MNISTGen, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            # input is (num_input_channels*4) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(num_channels * 4, num_channels * 2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels * 2),
            # nn.ReLU(True),
            # size. (num_channels*2) x 7 x 7
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(num_channels * 2, num_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels),
            # nn.ReLU(True),
            # size. (num_channels) x 14 x 14
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(num_channels, num_input_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_input_channels),
            nn.Sigmoid()  # the final output image size. (num_input_channels) x 28 x 28
        )
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            # size. (latent_vec_size)
            nn.Linear(latent_vec_size, 64),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            # nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # size. (64)
            nn.Linear(64, 256),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            # size. 256
            nn.Linear(256, 512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            # size. 512
            nn.Linear(512, (num_channels * 4) * 4 * 4),
            nn.BatchNorm1d((num_channels * 4) * 4 * 4),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        x = x.view(-1, num_channels * 4, 4, 4)
        return self.conv(x)


class MNISTDisc(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_input_channels):
        super(MNISTDisc, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            # input is (num_input_channels) x 28 x 28
            nn.Conv2d(num_input_channels, num_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # size. (num_channels) x 14 x 14
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels, num_channels * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # size. (num_channels*2) x 7 x 7
            nn.Conv2d(num_channels * 2, num_channels * 4, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_channels * 4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),  # size. (num_channels*4) x 4 x 4
        )
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            # size. (num_channels_d*4) x 4 x 4
            nn.Linear((num_channels * 4) * 4 * 4, 512),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # size. (512)
            nn.Linear(512, 256),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256),
            # size. 256
            nn.Linear(256, 64),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
            # size. 64
            nn.Linear(64, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()  # final classification
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = x.view(-1, (num_channels * 4) * 4 * 4)  # reshape input so that it fits fc layer
        return self.linear(x)


def train(g_net: nn.Module, d_net: nn.Module):
    G_losses, D_losses, iters, gen_lst = [], [], 0, []
    optimizerD = optim.Adam(d_net.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
    optimizerG = optim.Adam(g_net.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
    print("Starting Training Loop...")
    # For each epoch
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # For each batch in the dataloader
        for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
            ############################
            # (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
            ###########################
            # Train with all-real batch
            d_net.zero_grad()
            # Format batch
            real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
            b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
            # Forward pass real batch through D
            real_output = d_net(real_cpu).view(-1)
            # errD_real.backward()
            D_x = real_output.mean().item()

            # Train with all-fake batch
            # Generate batch of latent vectors
            noise = torch.randn(b_size, latent_vec_size, device=device)
            # Generate fake image batch with G
            fake = g_net(noise)
            # Classify all fake batch with D
            fake_output = d_net(fake.detach()).view(-1)
            # Calculate the gradients for this batch, accumulated (summed) with previous gradients
            loss = d_loss(fake_output, real_output)
            loss.backward()
            # errD_fake.backward()
            D_G_z1 = fake_output.mean().item()
            # Compute error of D as sum over the fake and the real batches
            errD = loss
            # Update D
            optimizerD.step()

            # perform a generator iteration every 'discriminator_iterations' steps of the discriminator
            if i % discriminator_iterations == 0:
                ############################
                # (2) Update G network: maximize log(D(G(z)))
                ###########################
                g_net.zero_grad()
                # Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
                fake_output = d_net(fake).view(-1)
                # Calculate G's loss based on this output
                # errG = criterion(fake_output, label)
                errG = gen_loss_non_saturating(fake_output)
                # Calculate gradients for G
                errG.backward()
                D_G_z2 = fake_output.mean().item()
                # Update G
                optimizerG.step()

                # Output training stats
                if i % 50 == 0:
                    print('[%d/%d][%d/%d]\tLoss_D: %.4f\tLoss_G: %.4f\tD(x): %.4f\tD(G(z)): %.4f / %.4f'
                          % (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                             errD.item(), errG.item(), D_x, D_G_z1, D_G_z2))
                G_losses.append(errG.item())

            D_losses.append(errD.item())  # Save Losses for plotting later

            # Check how the generator is doing by saving G's output on fixed_noise
            if (iters % 500 == 0) or ((epoch == num_epochs - 1) and (i == len(dataloader) - 1)):
                with torch.no_grad():
                    fake = g_net(fixed_noise).detach().cpu()
                gen_lst.append(vutils.make_grid(fake))
                plt.imshow(tensor_to_plt_im(gen_lst[-1]))
                plt.show()
            iters += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataloader = generate_mnist_data_set()
    generator = MNISTGen(num_input_channels=1)
    discriminator = MNISTDisc(num_input_channels=1)

    generator.apply(weights_init), discriminator.apply(weights_init)

    # Create batch of latent vectors that we will use to visualize
    #  the progression of the generator
    fixed_noise = torch.randn(image_size, latent_vec_size, device=device)
    train(generator, discriminator)
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, remarks and general directions because like I said, I am completely stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> both the generator and discriminator are stuck (.i.e. the loss values won't change

That's how GAN's training process works. Note that those two neural networks 'learn' from one another. Run the training without paying attention to the loss value and check the results after some time.

[image]

Note that depending on the problem and hardware the training might take hours or even days.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I will try again and hope for good results. Thank you!